# Why doesn't kickstart for CentOS 7 use my disk configuration?

Tags: centos, kickstart, pxe

I have exhausted [Redhat's syntax guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/installation_guide/sect-kickstart-syntax), their [advanced partitioning example](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/installation_guide/sect-kickstart-examples#sect-kickstart-partitioning-example_), and a [complex partitioning example](https://dark.ca/2009/08/03/complex-partitioning-in-kickstart/) on someone's blog. I have a fairly simple setup I want to achieve.

Here is my kickstart file:

```
#version=DEVEL
# System authorization information
auth --enableshadow --passalgo=sha512
# Use graphical install
graphical
# Use NFS installation media
nfs --server={MY PXE SERVER IP} --dir=/path/to/centos/7/
# Run the Setup Agent on first boot
firstboot --disable
ignoredisk --only-use=sda,sdb
eula --agreed

# Keyboard layouts
keyboard --vckeymap=us --xlayouts='us'
# System language
lang en_US.UTF-8

# Network information
network  --bootproto=dhcp --device=eno16777984 --ipv6=auto --activate
network  --hostname=myhostname.example.com

# Root password
rootpw --iscrypted {REDACTED}

# System services
services --enabled="chronyd"
# System timezone
timezone America/Denver --isUtc --ntpservers=MY_NTP1.example.com,MY_NTP2.example.com

# System bootloader configuration
bootloader --append=" crashkernel=auto" --location=mbr --boot-drive=sda

# Partition clearing information
clearpart --all --initlabel

# Primary drive partition
part sda1 --size=1024 --fstype=xfs --ondisk=sda
part /boot --size=1024 --onpart=sda1
part pv.sda2 --size=1 --grow --encrypted --fstype=xfs --ondisk=sda

# LVM for sda
volgroup vg_a pv.sda2
logvol / --vgname=vg_a --size=51200 --name=vg_a-root --fstype=xfs
logvol swap --vgname=vg_a --recommended --name=vg_a-swap
logvol /home --vgname=vg_a --size=1 --grow --name=vg_a-home --fstype=xfs

# Secondary drive partition
part pv.sdb1 --size=1 --grow --encrypted --fstype=xfs --ondisk=sdb

# LVM for sdb
volgroup vg_b pv.sdb1
logvol /storage --vgname=vg_b --size=1 --grow --name=vg_b-storage --fstype=xfs

repo --name=MyRepoName --baseurl=http://myhostname.example.com/path --install

%packages
@^compute-node-environment
@base
@core
@directory-client
@scientific
chrony
kexec-tools

%end

%addon com_redhat_kdump --enable --reserve-mb='auto'

%end
```

I have verified it is valid using `ksvalidator`.

For whatever reason, when the installation GUI comes up, it tells me I need to select my installation disks. So I go in, and none of my configurations from my file seem to be applied.

In fact, the partitions from my previous installation still exist. That is, I have to decrypt the drives with my old password. So the original partitions aren't even being cleared.

Once I unencrypt them, I have to manually set mount points, reformatting, encryption, device types, etc.

Is there something obvious I am missing?

As a minor secondary question, what does `--asprimary` do for `part`? I keep seeing it everywhere but haven't found a description.

I know my general configuration outside of partitioning is correct, as I have done an automated version using

```
autopart --type=lvm --encrypted
```

but I need a custom configuration because this groups my entire `sdb` drive with the logical volume for `/home` with `sda`.

EDIT:

Ok so I went ahead and manually configured everything in the installation GUI to how I wanted it, and then opened up `/root/anaconda.cfg` to see what lines were generated. (Also note, I am finding my config in `/root/original.cfg` so I know its loading properly)

This is what i found for the disk configuration (everything else was the same):

```
clearpart --all --initlabel --drives=sda,sdb

part /storage --fstype="xfs" --size=1 --grow --encrypted
part pv.2717 --fstype="lvmpv" --ondisk=sda  --size=284543
part /boot --fstype="xfs" --ondisk=sda  --size=1024

volgroup cl_newegg00 --pesize=4096 pv.2717

logvol swap --fstype="swap" --size=28532  --encrypted --name=swap --vgname=cl_newegg00
logvol /home --fstype="xfs" --size=204802  --encrypted --name=home --vgname=cl_newegg00
logvol root --fstype="xfs" --size=51202  --encrypted --name=root --vgname=cl_newegg00
```

So I thought if I just replaced my config with these lines, everything should work. But I am still experiencing the same behavior, i.e. having to unlock the drives, set there mount points, set encryption, set type, etc. Seems like this is completely defeating the purpose of a kickstart file.

EDIT:

So I've made some minor changes, and switched to `text` mode and I've discovered in my `/tmp/*.log` files a couple errors:

```
grep ERR /tmp/*.log
.. ERR: LUKS device sda has no key/passphrase
.. ERR: LUKS device sdb has no key/passphrase
```

I was under the impression it would ask me for a passphrase. I see tons of bug reports in google search but many of them are not recent. I get the same results in graphical mode. Seems like what I am trying to do is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what I've been trying to achieve is not possible. I found [reports](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1436304) of others experiencing the same issue. There is a way to get around this though with some post installation work:

```
cryptsetup luksChangeKey /dev/sdX
```

Additionally you can create a keyfile and set up mounting at boot:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=/root/keyfile bs=1024 count=4
cryptsetup luksAddKey /dev/sdX /root/keyfile

# /etc/crypttab
sdX_crypt      /dev/sdX  /root/keyfile  luks

# /etc/fstab
/dev/mapper/sdX_crypt  /media/sdX     ext3    defaults        0       2
```

Note: A keyfile can't be used if the partition it is on hasn't been decrypted. So you can create keys for every partition, but to unlock everything you need to enter a passphrase for a drive with the keys on it.

---

I have came up with a hack that works for me, using the %pre section and bash.

```
%pre
#!/bin/sh

TTY=`tty`
exec < $TTY > $TTY 2> $TTY


pswd1=a
pswd2=b
while [ ! $pswd1 == $pswd2 ]; do
    read -s -p "Enter encryption passphrase: " pswd1
    echo -e ""
    read -s -p "Enter passphrase again: " pswd2
    echo -e ""
    if [ ! $pswd1 == $pswd2 ]; then
        echo -e "Password does not match. Try again."
    fi
done

PASSPHRASE=$pswd1

cat << EOF > /tmp/part-include
    ...
    part .... --passphrase=${PASSPHRASE}
    part .... --passphrase=${PASSPHRASE}
    ...
EOF

%end

%include /tmp/part-include
```

Fill in your custom partitioning which gets written to a file, and included as a part of the kickstart installation after the %pre bash section has been evaluated.